# Marquee scrolling gallery with flexible layout

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to set up a scrolling gallery, but not sure how to proceed.

The following is what I'm looking for (see attached as well):

1. 15-20 images with different sizes
2. Define spacing between the images (pink areas)
3. The container to be the specific height on certain breakpoints (desktop, tablet, mobile), and then which the images will adapt to in order to keep their ratios and layout according to my attached example.
4. Scroll from right to left and start over once the last image is being shown, so it starts over smooth.

I'm thinking the following, but don't know how to make the images adopt the right way depending on screen size?

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    max-height: 700px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.image{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[image]

Comment: "Define spacing between the images (pink areas)" -- the way you write this it sounds as if perhaps there is an example image you are referencing that is not included in the question?

Comment: @AlexanderNied yes sorry, it has been updated with the attached.